# Firing change event when knockout view model property is updated

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

Here's a jsfiddle to show what the issue is:

http://jsfiddle.net/boblauer/BgvV4/

I'm trying to fire the change event after a text field is updated.  Unfortunately, inside the subscribe method, the text box's value hasn't been updated yet, so when I figure the change event, it's fired too soon.

I need to fire the change event because I have 3rd party code that is out of my control that relies on the change event.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Is the change event being set in 3rd party code, or are you just required to call it?

Comment: The change event handler is bound in 3rd party code, and I need to trigger it when my view model updates my textbox value.

Comment: Maybe I'm not following you. If you want to trap the new value (the one it was changed to) then the subscribe method is fine and in your example it is working. Since I am missing something, what is your expected results?

Comment: I would expect that inside the subscribe method, the DOM would already be updated, so I could fire my input field's onchange event, and have the new value be set when the event fires.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A simple solution is to wrap your call to $("#text1").change() in a setTimeout with a timeout of 0.  That's enough to let knockout do the (synchronous) update to the textbox value before the jquery change handler gets invoked.

I forked your fiddle to demonstrate:
[http://jsfiddle.net/SuRYa/1//](http://jsfiddle.net/SuRYa/1/)

If this is something you need to do a lot, a better solution is probably to wrap this behavior in a custom binding where the "update" callback of the binding would fire the jquery change event on the updated element.

Comment: Not an ideal solution, but I am not convinced an ideal solution exists, so I think this might be my best option.  Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

bmode is right, a custom binding will do it. Although this answer is a bit late, here is the binding in case it helps anyone subsequently reading this post. It updates the value of the textbox using jQuery - the DOM is now updated in order for Bob's 3rd party code to work - so then it fires the change event.

```
ko.bindingHandlers.valueAndFireChange = {
    update: function(element, valueAccessor) {
        var val = ko.unwrap(valueAccessor());
        if (val == undefined) return;
        $(element).val(val);
        $(element).change();
    }
};
```

Here's an updated version of Bob's fiddle showing this in action:

http://jsfiddle.net/BgvV4/17/

I changed the alerts to console.log, so you'll need the console open to see the useful info.